# Google Analytics: What exactly is "Goal Previous Step 1"?

Tags: google-analytics

Within the Secondary dimension, there are *Goal Previous Step 1*, *Goal Previous Step 2* and *Goal Previous Step 3*. I couldn't figure out what they mean and how to make use of them.

[image: Secondary dimension]

I guess it's got nothing to do with the funnels. In my goal setup, I only have a single step funnel for my destination goal type.

Answer (score 1):

This is to specify what had to have happened before the user entered the funnel. So for example, if you want to view a report on users who came from your Products page right before entering the funnel, you'd specify that page in Step 1. If the user took a series of steps to get to your funnel, you'd keep adding to it. It is truly a reverse funnel - referred to officially as a reverse goal path.